# Как перекинуть список из view в контроллер

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

Есть view, который принимает `@model List<MyClass>` и форма в нем, которая при нажатии должна пополнять список.

```
@model System.Collections.Generic.List<MyClass>
    <form method="post" action="~/MyClass/Add">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><p>A</p></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="A" /> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p>B</p></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="B" /> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Сохранить" /> </td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

И получается так, что после того как я отправлю форму, лист не пополнится. Как мне отправить модель в контроллер или может ее можно как-то использовать внутри контроллера не отправляя? Мне нужно, чтобы при отправке формы пополнялся лист. Ну или не обязательно формы, главное пополнять его. Может это можно как-то сделать легче, но у меня пока что нет других идей.

upd: Возможно стоит хранить где-то все эти поля. В куках. Или может где-то можно удобно хранить списки.

Answer (score 0):

Если я верно понял, то ты можешь просто сделать строку в духе "element1 element2", либо же "element1, element2" как тебе будет удобно. И отправить ее в контроллер, после разобрав ее например так: `var userList = users.Split(" ");`